# Original poster's own comments invalidate criteria for Tumbleweed badge - should it be so?

Tags: discussion, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712427/find-and-exclude-visits-via-top-sites-function) 7 days ago with around 20 views, no answers. Soon after I posted the question, I added a comment, saying that I don't really know how to tag the question, and asking people for help. Afterwards, I edited this same message into the question.

However, after a week's time, no one's answered, and no other activity has taken place with the question.

Regardless, I have not been awarded the Tumbleweed badge.

---

Here's the definition of the "definition" of the Tumbleweed badge, as per the Badges page:

> Tumbleweed - Asked a question with no
>   answers, **no comments**, and low views
>   for a week

There are two reasons why I think that might have happened with my question:

- 20 views does not constitute "low" views - this has already been discussed, and I don't think this is the case here.
- **I added a comment to my own question** - The badge details state "no comments".

As I think that it is because of the comment I myself added, why should this not qualify for Tumbleweed?

In other words, **why should comments you yourself add to such an under-viewed and unanswered question count against the "no comments" clause**?

---

As far as I understand, the purpose of the badge is to sort of like a cookie:

> No one has helped you yet (answered/looked at your
>   question for a week), so here's a bone.

However, the **poster of a question would naturally leave comments to clarify**.

On the other hand, if someone else were to leave a comment, that means that some activity with other users would be going on with that question, so it would disqualify your question from Tumbleweed.

---

In conclusion, the original poster's own comments should not count as "regular" comments for the Tumbleweed badge. We should only have other people's comments disqualify questions from attaining this badge.

What do you think?

Comment: Naturally you would edit the actual question if you had to clarify and not leave it to the comments where it may be hidden.

Comment: @random I will keep that in mind for future situations, but I still think that OP's comments shouldn't disqualify the question.

Comment: I wish I'd realised that before I got *my* Tumbleweed Badge (for the SPC question). I'm not particularly proud of it - it seems more of a failure than a success.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer or for a badge?

Comment: Who cares about answers, Manni?

Comment: Guess what? I got tumbleweed today! I think it's because I removed that comment I made on my own question.

Answer (score 3):

Why?  Query optimization I suppose... :-) or they just overlooked that special case.

**EDIT**: to actually answer the question. I don't think it is right that the OPs activity on their own question should affect the tumbleweed badge calculation.

While I agree with random's assessment that you should edit the question, rather then leave comments, if you are trying to clarify it still goes against the idea of "we're sorry no one could help you, here's a bone" that the tumbleweed badge is supposed to be.

I suspect that in most cases any activity by an OP on their own unanswered question, be it edits or comments, is trying to get answered and that is a good thing.

Undoubtedly some freak OP will make that statement untrue but human behavior is not deterministic so the OP should get the benefit of the doubt and be awarded the tumbleweed badge even if they left a few comments on an otherwise unanswered, un-commneted, low-view question.

Comment: However, do you think this is the optimal solution?

Comment: If I had to come down on one side or the other?  No, I think OP activity should not affect the tumbleweed calculations.