# Tumbleweed badge: Own comments

Tags: support, comments, badges, tumbleweed-badge

Do your own comments count if you want to earn the Tumbleweed badge?

Comment: So you WANT to get a Tumbleweed??

Comment: Yes, I want all badges. Especially Tumbleweed, because I like the name  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30304/original-posters-own-comments-invalidate-criteria-for-tumbleweed-badge-should), they do contribute towards blocking the Tumbleweed badge. All other requirements for the badge were met, and the user did not get Tumbleweed until after deleting an author comment on the post.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more on this please?

"All other requirements for the badge were met, and the user did not get Tumbleweed until after deleting an author comment on the post."

Comment: @Z0q The requirements are: no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views. The [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1712427/timeline) proves the first two even to this day, while the "low views" is taken simply by acknowledgement of the badge eventually being received. In essence, I'm just explaining that the only possible thing blocking the Tumbleweed badge in that instant was the author's own comment, and deleting it led to the badge being awarded.